# ECDSA public key recovery is discovered by whom?

Tags: elliptic-curves, history

I'm looking for the history of the method (ECDSA public key recovery from signature). Where did this implementation first appear in (is it bitcoin?) and who discovered this method?

Comment: This is the earliest mentioning I found:  Daniel R. L. Brown, SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography (2009) -- [4.1.6 Public Key Recovery Operation](http://bitcoin.me/sec1-v2.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: in a footnote of his paper [Generic Groups, Collision Resistance, and ECDSA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/026) (online since 2002-02-27), then published [in Designs, Codes and Cryptography](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10623-003-6154-z) (2005), Daniel R. L. Brown wrote that

> In ECDSA, the public key can be recovered from the message and the signature.

Then, acting as editor of the [SEC 1 standard](https://www.secg.org), he [put there](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=53) how such ECDSA public key recovery can be made. In [this version](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v1.99.dif.pdf#page=56) v1.99 of 2009-05-21 with changes since v1.5 visible, that section appears as a late addition.

Thus it seems possible that Daniel R. L. Brown of Certicom came up with ECDSA public key recovery circa 2002. At least he knew about its feasibility. That vastly predates Bitcoin.

Comment: I'll accept this as answer for the moment since there isn't a better answer